# MS-SQL SmallDateTime To NSDate Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, wcf, ios6

The application on which in am currently working is an iPhone app and the backend is in .Net. The iPhone application consumes WCF RestFul API. The database that the server is using is MS SQL and the Client-side in objective-c(xcode4.5,iOS6). I store date in the form of smallDateTime on server-side. On getting this date back in the JSON format, i convert it to NSDate with the below mentioned code.Following is a sample date string that i receive from the  server (serverDate=/Date(1356527635798+0500)/).

Following is iPhone side code for conversion.

```
+ (NSDate *)convertServerDateToNSDate:(NSString *)serverDate
{
    serverDate = [serverDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    serverDate = [serverDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@""];
    if(serverDate == nil)
    return nil;

    NSDate * nsDate;

    NSCharacterSet * tempSet1 = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"("];

    serverDate = [serverDate stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"+"];

    NSCharacterSet * tempSet2 = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+"];

    NSRange startRange = [serverDate rangeOfCharacterFromSet:tempSet1];
    NSRange endRange = [serverDate rangeOfCharacterFromSet:tempSet2];
    NSRange actualRange;
    actualRange.location = startRange.location + 1;
    actualRange.length = endRange.location - actualRange.location;

    NSString * tempString = [serverDate substringWithRange:actualRange];
    double timeInSecs = [tempString doubleValue]/1000;

    nsDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInSecs];
    return nsDate;
}
```

The Date conversion is perfect on iOS-Simulator 6.0, But date is converted one day less on my ipod. I tried to search it and do it myself but everytime i am getting 1 day less than the actually date.

1) What is the problem ?

2) How can i resolve it ?

3) I ensured that locale is same both on simulator and on iPod.

Any help in this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are `timeInSecs` same between Simulator and your iPodTouch?

Comment: 1356535379192 is tempString incase of iPod,  1356535441441 is tempString incase of simulator.

Comment: For the same `serverDate`? 
Then, check all the local variables and you will be able to find the cause by yourself.

Comment: Yes for same serverDate, But i didn't used here any kind of iPod-specific variables.

Comment: i got a solution, it works fine on iPhone. Still not works correctly on iPod.